# Is there a way remove redundant checks for an early method return in Java?

Tags: java, refactoring, code-formatting

I've seen this code pattern a few times over the years.  Its the process of continually checking for a certain criteria where, if met, the method exits early.  Is there a way to refactor this code to remove some of the redundant checks so that you don't have to continuously check the response from each supporting method?

For example:

```
public String process(String s) {
    String revised = doActionA(s);
    if (checkCriteria(revised)) return revised;

    revised = doActionB(revised);
    if (checkCriteria(revised)) return revised;

    return doActionC(revised);
}
```

Comment: In what way are those checks redundant? You're checking the result of each action... it doesn't feel like there's any redundancy here.

Comment: You should always check the input, if you mark a method as public. A more relaxed convention is to do so only in framework code. Yet another method is to define the perimeter of you layer and check only at its bounds. But this also means to change the visibility of the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want here is the [Chain of responsibility - Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).
You'll need an 'Function': `String -> String` and a List, that contains those Functions. An evaluator will call each one of these and in the case of success, it will not call the remainding one - which is what you have in your example as well.

The term 'Function' could be anything from Java 8 Function Interface, Google Guava Function Interface or just a specialized [functional interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6) like

```
public interface {
  String doAction(String parameterS);
}
```

You'll need to configure the evaluator before you use it with the 'Functions' / 'Actions' it should try.
That could be as easy as adding them to the list, but you might want to extract that to a separate class as well.

If you want some examples, I think Google will provide you with plenty of them.